# I have an img that refuses to center and I can't figure out why?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I can't seem to center an image I have. The image is in a `div` surrounded by 2 other images. I have tried `text-align` and setting `margin` to `auto` but that doesn't seem to be working. The `slider` div below holding the slides should be centered but it's not.

Here's the html:

```
<body>
<div id = "container">
  <h1>
   Meet some of of our Members
  </h1>
  <img id="prev" src="images/rsz_back-button.png" alt="prev">
  <div id="Slider">
    <div class = "slide active">
      <div id ="slide-copy">
        <h2>
        Echo
        </h2>
      </div>
      <img src="images/rsz_a0615655ad9ed49f75bf617e2df6a47c.jpg"> </div>

  <div class = "slide">
    <div id ="slide-copy">
      <h2>
      Victor
      </h2>
    </div>
    <img src="images/rsz_dollhouse-tv-show-2.jpg"> </div>
  <div class = "slide">
    <div id ="slide-copy">
      <h2>
      Sierra
      </h2>
    </div>
    <img src="images/rsz_0000053222_20081110111439.jpg"> </div>
  <div class = "slide">
    <div id ="slide-copy">
      <h2>
      Alpha
      </h2>
    </div>
    <img  src="images/rsz_1alan-tudyk-transformers.jpg"> </div>
    </div>
  <img id="next" src="images/rsz_forward-button.png" alt="next"> </div>
</body>
```

and here is the css:

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body{
    font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#333;
    line-height:1.6em;
}

a{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}

h1{
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

#container{
    text-align:center;
    width: 980px;
    margin:40px auto;
    overflow:hidden;    
}

#slider{
    margin:40px auto;
    position:relative;
    width:512px;
    height:385px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    padding:3px;
    border: #666 solid 2px;
    border-radius:2px;
    z-index:0;

}

slider img{
    width:512px;
    height:385;
}

#prev, #next{
    float:left;
    padding-top:50px;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: please try and add a fiddle. We don't have your folder `images` and its content.

Comment: Can you provide better sample of the problem? Maybe a link to the actually working code? Or at least jsfiddle sample? Do you want it center horizontally or vertically? Also you didn't write here all the css - where is class "slide"? Thats really important. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#Slider` div comes right after the floating `#prev` div, which pushes the `#Slider` to the right.

Solution: don't float the `#prev`. Or clear the float in the `#Slider`, whatever you want. (If your intention is to show the `#prev` to the left of the screen, give it `position:absolute` or something.)

By the way, there are errors in your HTML. The ID `slide-copy` appears twice.
And errors in your css. `385` should be `385px`, and `slider` and `#slider` should both be `#Slider`.

Comment: thank you, this kind of worked. Also thanks for catching my errors. I still floated both, but moving the float to the bottom of the css #slider{} seemed to fix it.

Comment: If the solution works, can you accept this answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left. That way, it will no loner show up in the list of unsolved questions. But if it only "kind of" works, what should be done to improve it?

Comment: I'm guessing it was the uppercase lowercase "s" in slider that I had capitalized by accident in the HTML because after that was changed everything worked.

Comment: Ah, OK. You also had `slider` without `#` in the CSS once, but I guess that was just an attempt to get it right, right?